# Защищенная отправка GET запроса через URLOpenBlockingStream

Tags: php, c++, visual-studio, сокет, websocket

В общем я отправляю GET запрос с приставкой https:// на свой хост на котором установлен SLL сертификат c поддержкой HSTS, SSI, Wildcard и проверка подлинности через DNS. При отправки Fiddler показывает [это(кликабельно)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgE7V.png)
На скриншоте видно что запрос - тунель а ответ можно перехватить и изменить.
**Мне нужно чтобы все подключения были тунелем ака чтобы нельзя было подменить ответ от сервера**

Comment: непонятен смысл вопроса

Comment: Что тут не понятно?

Comment: что фиксить то? ну не отправляйте get запросом отправляйте post. А может у вас дешманский хостинг и стоит прокси.

Comment: Как отправлять? Я незнаю больше других способов, Знаю есть винсок который дерьмовый и для меня самый адекватный это curl но я не знаю что и где качать и как это инклюдить ибо гайдов нету.

Comment: Выдели проблему `в чем ссуть, чего не получается`

Comment: Так понятно? и почему вам не ясна проблема? разве когда ответ от сервера не зашифрован и его можно подменить на что угодно это хорошо???

Comment: Как вы перехватите его без соответствующего сертификата вы не рассшифруете его это раз, и два вы по незащищёному протоколу `http` обращаетесь в порт `443` как это вообще можно понять?

Comment: Тоннель (tunnel, второй запрос) - это туннель от Fiddler к вашему серверу по HTTPS протоколу. Если вы не доверяете ему, то составьте запрос используя код с CURL и SSL проверкой, либо же в unix консоли исполните curl запрос с отладочной информацией (-vvv), которая вам покажет, используется ли сертификат или нет. Первый запрос в Фидлере - это ваш запрос, перехваченный им, так как Фидлер служит промежуточным звеном (man-in-the-middle) для предоставления внутренностей запросов-ответов, и он осуществляет SSL аутентификацию с сервером.